# How to sanitize script before injecting into body

Tags: javascript, firefox, sanitize

I am creating a Firefox jetpack addon which fetches data for the opened URL in tab from an API. The API returns data in JSON format. I then use that data to create HTML tags for the purpose of nicely displaying it. I then inject that HTML from content-script file to the body of the opened site. This works perfectly fine but as I submitted the application to Firefox store for review, it got rejected because of unsanitized data.

If I sanitize it, it then displays plain HTML in the injection. I have got no < script > tags in the created document but I use onclick function for a few links inside the injected script. Here is an example code to get an idea as to what I am trying to achieve.

Main.js

```
// It gets data in JSON format
// I share this data with content script in an object
tab = tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile:  [require("sdk/self").data.url("jquery.min.js"),
                                require("sdk/self").data.url("contentscript.js")]
                    });
tab.port.emit('data', JSON.parse(JSON_STRING));
```

contentscript.js

```
// I get data from main.js and then make an html 
// then I inject it to the opened document
self.port.on('data', function(obj) {
 content = '<div id="test"><a href="http://www.example.com/'+obj.page+'" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById(\'test\').style.display="none">Visit</a></div>';
 $('body').append(content);

});
```

I also use css styles in extension.

Any solution to sanitize it without breaking the functionality? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used the escapeHTML() function from Mozilla website and it resolved my issue. Here's the code and it's usage:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com'; // any internal/external variable
var content = '<div id="main_extension"><a href="'+escapeHTML(url)+'">Click Me</a></div>';

function escapeHTML(str) str.replace(/[&"<>]/g, function (m) escapeHTML.replacements[m]);
escapeHTML.replacements = { "&": "&amp;", '"': "&quot;", "<": "&lt;", ">": "&gt;" };
```

My extension got approved using this method. However, you can use other methods as well if you are using jQuery DOM or any other for data injection. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion